# How to create a react project with specific version of create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I need to create a new react application with `create-react-app` version **1.0.10**. However, when I do `create-react-app myProject` it automatically uses the latest version of `create-react-app` available at that time. Is there any commands available to make create-react-app use a specific version to create a project template?

Comment: Did you try installing 1.0.10? `npm install create-react-app@1.0.10`? Most likely it's installed globally so you'd have to install it locally and then run it from there.

Comment: you mean installing it locally in a project?

Comment: `create-react-app` is a global package, so you have 1 version of that package installed globally on your machine and wherever you are in your computer, you can type `create-react-app myProject`. As @HenrikAndersson suggested, if you install globally a specific version: `npm -g install create-react-app@1.0.10` every time you use it, it's going to be that version

Comment: You could specify    "create-react-app":"1.0.10." in package.json, and then do "npm install" and then it should install the package for you(note this is without the package being installed already).

Answer (score 5):

You will need to run:

`npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@1.0.10`

or

`yarn add --exact react-scripts@1.0.10`

this will only work in in a project that has not been ejected yet, read [this](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#updating-to-new-releases) for more info